# Modification required to transform a checkbox to a three-state one in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have a checkbox defined as follows:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="T09_CH105" IsChecked="{Binding Path=T09_CH105,Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Others"/>
```

And its corresponding DataMember:

```
[DataMember]
public Boolean T09_CH105 {
  get { return _T09_CH105; }
        set { if (_T09_CH105 != value) {
            _T09_CH105 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("T09_CH105");
          }
      }
  }
```

How can I make it a three-state checkbox ? I haven't been able to figure out how to adapt what I've read online to my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nullable bool: `bool?` or `Nullable<bool>` (see the [corresponding msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) for reference)

If the status is null the wpf checkbox displays a "half checked" state.

Answer (score 3):

you should add the attribute:

```
IsThreeState="True"
```

to your XAML

Comment: Have also a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b53a961c-18cb-4d10-a2df-52280b8f83b6/